# How do I craft a fishing pole?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I have Terraria for my Android device, and I can't make a fishing pole. I need help.

Answer (score 2):

In order to make a wooden fishing pole you need 8 wood and need to be standing near a work bench.

The other three craftable rods are made at a lead or iron anvil with 8 lead or iron bars, 8 demonite bars or 8 crimtane bars.

There are 5 more rods which are not craftable, you can see how to get each of them [on this site](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Fishing_Pole#Non-craftable).

Comment: I've tried to craft one but, It won't work

Comment: what do you mean by it won't work, does it show up in the craft list? can you post a screenshot?

Comment: It doesn't show up in the draft list even, when I grab everything I need

Comment: @Nick Are you near a workbench when you try to craft it?

Comment: Yes @PrivatePansy